# How to include `:` in an http path in an Armeria Server?

Tags: armeria

I want to create an endpoint similar to this:

```
POST /someresource:validate
```

Based on [Google API Guideliness](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods#http_mapping) for custom methods.

But when I add it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pathPattern: /someresource:validate (invalid pattern)
```

I think this happens because of [Path Pattern](https://armeria.dev/docs/server-basics/#path-patterns) syntax. Is there a way to configure so we can disable some syntax options so we can use `:` inside url names? Or is there another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the best workaround is to do something like the following for now:

```
sb.serviceUnder("/resource", (ctx, req) -> {
    final String nameAndVerb = req.path().substring(req.path().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    System.out.println(nameAndVerb);
    return HttpResponse.of(200);
});
```

I would expect something like the following to work, but it seems like there is a bug internally.

```
sb.service("exact:/resource/name:customVerb", (ctx, req) -> HttpResponse.of(200));
```

I've filed an issue for this.
https://github.com/line/armeria/issues/4577

Comment: Thanks for filing an issue. I thought about it but wanted to be sure that it's a bug before doing it.